# JQuery: Sliding Image down on Mouseover

Tags: jquery, css, slider

The fiddle I'm working with: http://jsfiddle.net/Hu4bg/1/

I'm trying to create a vertical menu and when you mouse over a link, I want an image(a div would be better as it has a content) to slide down and it would never slide up again, rather, when another link is hovered, it will slide down on the last image that slided down and on and on.

I think I should change the z-index values but I don't know how to control this thing via JQuery. Can you give me a quick tip on my fiddle?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#leftmenu a").hover(function() {
        $("#img1").slideDown(250);
    });

    $("#leftmenu a").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#img1").slideUp(250);
    });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/Hu4bg/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Hu4bg/3/

I have condensed the code into one event and **changed the way it works** (matches ids of multiple image boxes to classes of the links):

```
$("#leftmenu a").hover(function() {
    $("[id^=img]:not([id=" + $(this).attr("class") + "])").slideUp(250);
    $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).slideDown(250);
});
```

I also added 2 more `img` tags, with IDs that match the classes in the `a` tags:

```
<div id="img1">Image here</div>
<div id="img2">Image here</div>
<div id="img3">Image here</div>

<ul>
    <li> <a class="img1" href="#">Image 1</a></li>
    <li> <a class="img2" href="#">Image 2</a></li>
    <li> <a class="img3" href="#">Image 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well sort of. I don't like it to slide up though, it will only slide down, if you mouseover another link, another image (or div whatever) will slide down too, but the arrangement should change, it will bring image to forth, otherwise the one with higher z-index value will always be on top. (I assume z-index has something to do with that)

Answer (score 0):

`.hover` takes two arguments. One for mouse enter and the other for mouse leave.

```
$("#leftmenu a").hover(function() {
    $("#img1").slideDown(250);
}, function() {
    $("#img1").slideUp(250);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could actually do this with pure css by using `CSS Animation`.

Here's a [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Hp9gp/1/) of this.

Comment: Yeah but this thing is so new and people still stick to old stubborn browswers:)